# NodeJS socket on a port *and* a path?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I want to set up a basic socket on a URI like `ws://localhost:1234/mysocket` (to mimic another environment created with Java), Thus far I've only been able to set it up on `ws://localhost:1234/`  How can I get it to host on a specific URL beyond just a host and port?

This is just the basic NodeJS socket from the docs:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
  socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1'); // <-- not sure what to do here?
```

I'm specifically not asking for a solution involving Socket.IO.

#### Edit

I feel like maybe I actually need to set up a proxy in front of my socket server? But that seems a little bizarre.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're already using WebSockets, you can simply use the [ws](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ws) module:

```
var http = require('http'),
    WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var server = http.createServer();

var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    server: server,
    path: '/mysocket'
});

wss.on('connection', function (ws) {

    ws.send('echo server');

    ws.on('message', function (message) {
        ws.send(message);
    });

});

server.listen(1234);
```

Comment: This might do. I hadn't run across this module yet. I'll have a look.

Comment: I'm still curious how to do this with a base net.Socket though.

Comment: @BenLesh as far as I know (and I might be wrong), paths exist as part of the application protocol you're using (ie HTTP), so it doesn't make sense for vanilla sockets (TCP, a transport protocol) to support them.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with PURE node code, without a need for any external module, thanks